# How can I compile a C file in JetBrains CLion?

Tags: c, clion, jetbrains-ide

Using C programming language in JetBrains CLion IDE, I frequently make new C program files in the same project.

Is there any way to compile individual files directly in CLion?

Comment: Like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-single-file.html ?